# Default car speed?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, logic, game-physics

I have two buttons in my program. Left Button for brake (decreases speed) and right button for speed (increases speed). When nothing clicked, the car has a default speed. And there is a minimum (0.3) and maximum (2) speed. Now, I wrote this here:

```
private float _speed = 1f;


    if (ButtonClicked) {

        if (brake) {

            float tempSpeed = _speed;
            tempSpeed -= 0.05f;

            if (tempSpeed <= 0.3) {
                //
            } else {
                _speed -= 0.05f;
            }

        }           

        if (speed) {

            float tempSpeed = _speed;
            tempSpeed += 0.1f;

            if (tempSpeed >= 2) {
                //
            } else {
                _speed += 0.1f;
            }           

        }           

    } else {

        float tempSpeed = _speed;

        if (tempSpeed < 1) {
            _speed += 0.1f;
        }

        if (tempSpeed > 1) {
            _speed -= 0.1f;
        }
    }
```

The part, that I don't like is the 'else' part of 'ButtonsClicked'. It's the dafault car speed part. I increase or decrease the speed. The car moving looks not good, because of this increase or decrease. How can I make it better? I mean, when nothing clicked then good constant car speed without increase or decrease?

Comment: Why is there an *event* when nothing is happening? How do you get into that ``else``?

Comment: If you want a constant car speed, then remove the "else" part

Comment: When nobody clicks one of these buttons it goes to the else part.

Comment: When I delete the else part, where I increase or decrease to the default speed 1?

Comment: In what way does the movement not look good?  As a guess: your "default" acceleration is the same as your user-controlled acceleration - perhaps using a lower value would produce a better effect?  Try changing `0.1f` for `0.01f` in your `else` block, to see if that helps.

Comment: When you look at the car you see that the car is moving a little bit slower and a little bit faster. It's not moving smooth.

Comment: if you need to make the movement smoother, you can use smaller increments/decrements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that once it reaches the default speed, it will constantly accelerate/brake to remain at that speed. Since you question doesn't really explain the problem very well, we don't know for sure.

Here is an example of what I mean, you need to create a 'dead zone' around the default speed:

```
private final float MAX_SPEED = 2f;
private final float MIN_SPEED = 0.3f;

private final float DEFAULT_SPEED = 1f;

private final float ACCEL_SPEED = 0.1f;
private final float BRAKE_SPEED = 0.05f;

private float _speed = DEF_SPEED;

if (ButtonClicked)
{
    if (accelerate)
    {
        _speed = Math.min(_speed + ACCEL_SPEED, MAX_SPEED);
    }

    if (brake)
    {
        _speed = Math.max(_speed - BRAKE_SPEED, MIN_SPEED);
    }
}
else
{

    // only modify the speed if its far off to
    // prevent it from constantly accelerating and braking
    // (modify the 0.5f to increase/decrease the 'dead zone')
    if (Math.abs(_speed - DEFAULT_SPEED) > 0.5f)
    {
        // slowly reset to default speed
        if (_speed < DEFAULT_SPEED)
            _speed += ACCEL_SPEED;

        if (_speed > DEFAULT_SPEED)
            _speed -= BRAKE_SPEED;
    }
}
```